# Suddenly, pages_messaging_subscriptions permission is required

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

I have a simple message bot that was set up according to the Messenger Platform guide.  It has been working fine for the last few months, with about half a dozen messages sent a day. I have not touched it at all, but suddenly, sending a message, ie calling `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=...`, returns:

> {"message":"(#230) Requires pages_messaging_subscriptions permission to manage the object","type":"OAuthException","code":230,"fbtrace_id":"DVs...."}

This was out of the blue. Things were working fine, I did not even log on to Facebook during this time, and I haven't even looked at my webhook callback website.  But some time from Aug 17 onward, this exception was returned for every attempted message send.

Has something changed?  Anyway, I could not find a subscription field by the name `pages_messaging_subscriptions` in the Webhooks Page Subscription page.

What do I need to get my message bot to work again?

Comment: Can you provide an app id so we can check? Also, when was it created and when was it approved for the normal permission? That shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

August 15 was Updater Messenger Platform Policies.
[official post in blog](http://messengerblog.com/bots/updated-messenger-platform-policies-and-faster-review-times/)

Now, to send a message a day after the activity of the user is necessary to request additional permission in the application settings.
[image: screenshot of settings]

Comment: During development, is there a way to bypass this restriction so we can test our subscription messages before we've submitted the app for review?   e.g. for Admins of the page, allow the messages to go through.

Comment: @emilebaizel Yeah, testers/devs/admins shouldn't be affected by the permission. If they are, file a bugreport for Messenger Platform.

Comment: @dmitry that shouldn't affect existing apps.

Comment: @MikhailLarionov do you mean that apps created before this added permission doesn't need to ask for this permission ? thank you

Comment: @MikhailLarionov How does a user subscribe? How does my app know when a user has subscribed? I don't find an API for the subscribe operation.