# Send message to user periodically by using Api.ai

Tags: chatbot, messenger, dialogflow-es

I'm using Api.ai to make a chat-bot for health advice.

I want to send users about the recommended exercise plan daily. But the intent in Api.ai can only do response when users say something.

Should I do it by using the events? But how can I trigger an event to make it message users every day or like every n hours? Or is there any other solutions?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook killed that ability through the standard messaging permissions last year. You now have [24hrs to respond](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/08/15/updated-messenger-platform-policies/) to a user initiated message. There are a couple exceptions including:

- one bonus message outside the 24hrs
- [templates like recipes and airline boarding passes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/templates)

It looks like Facebook rolled out Subscription Messaging which requires an additional Facebook permission that needs to be add to your app [review submission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39073440/2056666).

---

Additionally, API.ai sessions expire.

> By default, contexts expire after either five requests or ten minutes
>   from the time they were activated. Intents that renew the context will
>   reset the counter and clock to give an additional five requests and
>   ten minutes.
>
> You can change the context lifespan in the settings of each context.
>
> https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-contexts#output-contexts

Although changing the lifespan may only increase the number of requests it lives for since there is no mention of increasing the time.

---

**TL;DR: Limitations and restrictions on both platforms mean this is likely not possible.**

Answer (score 0):

This would generally depend on the kind of integration that you have enabled for API.AI. To the best of my knowledge, there is nothing within API.AI that would allow for a cron job of sorts to send some notifications out.

In our scenario, we use Slack + API.AI and Slack provides an incoming Webhook notification to notify the whole channel or a specific user. But again, this notification code runs outside of API.AI

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide users the ability to subscribe and unsubscribe from push messages and fit one of three categories provide by Facebook to receive Messaging_subscription approval.

With approval complete or not if you just want to test. You would set up the following:

API.AI Subscribe and unsubscribe intent with an action assigned

The action would update a table with FBID so you know who wants to receive messages and who doesn't.

High level, you would create an service to broadcast to users using some kind of async task\job queue using the page token for your app. We use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-celery